# Is Node.js is used for developing client-side applications that run on the web browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud

I got this question during my ibm cloud application developer certification.
I know Node.js is runtime to run javascript server side but what is the correct answer of this question?

Comment: No! - is the correct answer for that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js allows you to run JavaScript on the server
It will be executed if someone tries to access a port on the server

thus Node JS is used for **server scripting**